# How to open and edit read-only word doc through VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a macro which should open, edit and copy the contents of read-only documents into a new document, then closes the original ones without saving. On my computer I get a runtime error 6124: "You are not allowed to edit this selection because it is protected."

When I open the document through VBA it says I am restricted with view only, however when I open it manually I get the notification that the author would like me to open it read only, and I can refuse.

The weird thing is I sent the macro to my colleague to test it, and the same code on the same files can do the editing for them.

Is there a setting I am not aware of that allows this to happen?
Is there a way to get VBA to open the read-only document with editing access?

I have tried to change the document attribute through runtime script, but it did not work:

```
Dim fso, doc As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set doc = fso.GetFile("path")

doc.Attributes = 0
Documents.Open("path")

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the read only attribute and not the "unblock" setting that is added when a file is sent thru email? https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5357-unblock-file-windows-10-a.html (look at option 1 screenshot)

Comment: The files were shared through Microsoft Teams and OneDrive. Also I have the issue with the original files, and they don't have it with the shared ones. I do not see the Security option to unblock it on the files I am using.